# Odoo v9 Webservice Report without layout

Tags: web-services, report, odoo-9

After following the documentation in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html I have encountered a problem with the generated PDF report.

I call the webservice to generate an invoice report and after rendering the pdf report, it returns without its layout ( located: account.report_invoice )

I do the following to render the report:

```
url = 'http://{0}:{1}/xmlrpc/2/report'.format(self._connect['host'], self._connect['port'])
sock_print = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)

#Here, the 'render_report' function returns  the base64 pdf without the specified layout 
result = sock_print.render_report(db_name, uid, pwd, report_name, ids, {'model': 'account.invoice', 'report_type': 'qweb-pdf'}) 
string_pdf = base64.decodestring(report['result'])
return True, string_pdf
```

After, the function above is done, I save the file in a directory to check if the file was generated with the correct layout.

So far, the pdf was generated but without its layout for account.report_invoice.

Any ideas on what might be happening or what I might be missing?

Thank you for your time.

[EDIT 1]

```
2018-09-17 14:34:09,599 30522 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2018 14:34:09] "GET /web/content/323-c1e807b/report.assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2018-09-17 14:34:09,617 30522 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2018 14:34:09] "GET /web/content/328-9a5a204/report.assets_pdf.0.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2018-09-17 14:34:09,879 30522 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2018 14:34:09] "GET /web/content/328-9a5a204/report.assets_pdf.0.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2018-09-17 14:34:09,883 30522 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2018 14:34:09] "GET /web/content/323-c1e807b/report.assets_common.0.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Found this when trying to call via webservice. 
When I print the reports directly from odoo interface it's O.K, but via webservice it doesn't recognise its own core css.

Comment: Is it your URL name localhost or other domain. Please check URL which you are accessing same as in setting--> system parameters -> web.base.url .

Comment: My DB is in, for e.g: 192.168.2.141 and the web.base.url is the same but my webservice is in, for e.g: 192.168.2.148 and doesn't have a front end to go to those settings.

Comment: how you are accessing odoo 192.168.2.141:8069 (any port number) ?

Comment: The webservice (192.168.2.148) connects to Odoo (192.168.2.141:8069) through the config.ini file.
Where I specify the host: 192.168.2.141 and the port: 8069 and the DB: «db_name». Then the methods are called via "xmlrpclib"